# Are the getters and setters necessary for this code to function?

Tags: java, setter, getter

I have included all my code below (5 Classes) for a simple database of students.

I cowrote this code with someone who believes that in the *Name*, *Address* and *Student* classes it is necessary to include all of the getters and setters that are currently there. I think the code will function without them and that they are not necessary and should be removed? If they are necessary could someone explain why or could someone confirm that they are not necessary?

#### Address Class

```
public class Address {

private String street, area, city, country;

public Address(String street, String area, String city, String country) {
    this.street = street;
    this.area = area;
    this.street = city;
    this.country = country;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public void setArea(String area) {
    this.area = area;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String street() {
    return street;
}

public String area() {
    return area;
}

public String city() {
    return city;
}

public String country() {
    return country;
}

    /** Returns area, street, city and country concatenated together respectively */
public String toString() {
    return area + ", " + street + ", " + city + ", " + country + ".";
}

    }
```

#### Name Class

```
public class Name{

private String firstName, lastName;

public Name (String firstName, String lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

/** Returns first name concatenated to last name */
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

}
```

#### Student Class

```
     public class Student {
    private Name name; // This is calling from the Name class, giving it the               name 'name'
    private Address address; // This calls from Address, giving it the name 'address'

    private char gender;

    private String course, college;

    private int gradePointAverage, id, age, level;

    public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String street, String area, String city, String country, int age, char gender, String college, String course,  int level, int gradePointAverage){ //This is the list of variables called from the Student class
        this.id = id;
        this.name = new Name(firstName, lastName);
        this.address = new Address(street, area, city, country);
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.college = college;
        this.course = course;
        this.level = level;
        this.gradePointAverage = gradePointAverage;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name.toString();
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address.toString();
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public char getGender(){
        return gender;
    }

    public String getCollege(){
        return college;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

     public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public int getGradePointAverage() {
        return gradePointAverage;
    }

    public void printStudent() {
        System.out.println("The Student " + name.toString() + " is logged under the student ID number " + id + ".");
        System.out.println("They live at " + address.toString() + " and their age is " + age + ".");
        System.out.println("Their gender is " + gender + ".");
        System.out.println("The student studies at " + college + " attending classes in " + course + ".");
        System.out.println("Their level is " + level + " and the student grade average in points is " + gradePointAverage + ".");
        System.out.println();
    }

    }
```

#### CollegeCommunity Class

```
    import java.util.*;

public class CollegeCommunity

    {

    private ArrayList<Student> students; // Setting up an arraylist to store student details




        public CollegeCommunity()

            {
                students = new ArrayList<Student>();
            }


        public void addStudent(Student student) // adds a student.

            {
                students.add(student); // .add method command.
            }


        public void removeStudent(int id) // deleting a student, after being passed id to locate desired student.

            {
                for (int i=0; i<students.size(); i++ ){ // using a loop to decide what student to remove by matching the student ID which was passed to the method with the student ID's on record. Once there's a match, the student will be removed (.remove).
                    if(students.get(i).getId()==id) {
                        students.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }


        public void showStudent(int id) // same as remove above but instead using print command to view details of particular student.

            {
                for (int i=0; i<students.size(); i++ ){
                    if(students.get(i).getId()==id) {
                        students.get(i).printStudent();
                   }
                }
            }


        public void showAllStudents()

            {
                for (int i=0; i<students.size(); i++ ){ // This loop command will display ALL student details as no specific ID was passed, so it will run as long as value 'i' is less than student.size.
                    int id=students.get(i).getId();
                        showStudent(id);
                }
            }


        public void showStudentsInCourse(String course) // This will show students in a particular course.

            {
                for(int i=0; i<students.size(); i++ ){ // Loop is same as remove but comparing the string course with the course of each student. .equals is used to compare strings.
                    if(students.get(i).getCourse().equals(course)){
                        int id=students.get(i).getId();
                            showStudent(id);
                    }
                }
            }


        public int calculateGradePointAverage() // calculating the grade point average as a percentage

        {
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++ ){
                total = total + students.get(i).getGradePointAverage(); // total is calculated as it loops, each students score (getGradePointAverage).
            }

            total = total / students.size(); // final figure is total divided by the number of students, to give an average score.

            return total;

        }
}
```

#### TestSystem Class

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class TestSystem

{
   public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Student student;
        CollegeCommunity collegeCommunity = new CollegeCommunity(); // New CollegeCommunity created called 'collegeCommunity'.

        int id, age, level, gradePointAverage; // ints created for student id, age, level of course, and the grade point value

        String fName,lName, street, area, city, country, course, college; // first name, last name strings created

        char gender; // character gender created

        boolean finish = false; // boolean finish has value of False.

            do

             {
                switch(getMenu())

                {

                    case '1':


                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter a new Student ID > ");
                        id = sc.nextInt();
                        sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the Student's first name > ");
                        fName = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the Student's last name > ");
                        lName = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the street > ");
                        street = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the area > ");
                        area = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the city > ");
                        city = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the country > ");
                        country = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the age > ");
                        age = sc.nextInt();

                        sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the gender > ");
                        gender = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the college > ");
                        college = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the course > ");
                        course = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter level > ");
                        level = sc.nextInt();

                        sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the average grade in points [0-100] > ");
                        gradePointAverage = sc.nextInt();

                        sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println();

                        student = new Student(id, fName, lName, street, area, city, country, age, gender, college, course, level, gradePointAverage);
                        collegeCommunity.addStudent(student);


                        break;


                    case '2':


                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the student ID number > ");
                        id = sc.nextInt();

                        sc.nextLine();
                        // this will delete the student selected
                        collegeCommunity.removeStudent(id);

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Student " + id + " has been deleted.");

                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println();

                        break;


                    case '3':


                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the student ID number > ");
                        id = sc.nextInt();

                        sc.nextLine();
                        // This will allow for the details of the selected student to be displayed. Calls stored data from community college.
                        collegeCommunity.showStudent(id);

                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println();

                        break;


                    case '4':


                        System.out.println();
                        // This will show all of the students stored in the system.
                        collegeCommunity.showAllStudents();

                        System.out.println();

                        break;


                    case '5':

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("Please enter the course > ");
                        course = sc.nextLine();
                        // This will show students that are enrolled in a chosen course.
                        collegeCommunity.showStudentsInCourse(course);

                        System.out.println();

                        break;

                    case '6':

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.print("The Average grade score is " + collegeCommunity.calculateGradePointAverage() + "%");

                        System.out.println();

                        break;

                    case 'x':
                    case 'X':

                        finish = true; // boolean value changes to true if X is selected

                        System.exit(0);

                    break;

                        default:

                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.println("That is an invalid selection.");

                        System.out.println("      Please try again");

                    break;

                    }

        }while (!finish);

    }

        public static char getMenu()

            {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("This is your community college menu");
                System.out.println("Please select from the menu options below");

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("1 Add a Student");

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("2 Delete a Student");

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("3 Show details on an individual student");

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("4 Show details on all students");

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("5 Shows details on all students on a course");

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("6 Display the average grade (points)");

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("X Exit");

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Please make selection > ");

                return sc.next().charAt(0);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Note that the Java convention for getters and setters is `getFoo` and `setFoo` instead of `foo` and `setFoo` (which is what Qt does, I believe).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always set the properties as `public` or `protected` or with default scope and access them (provided the class is in the appropiate package)

```
myStudent.age = 9;
```

That said, it is always good practice to use setters and getters. It eases control of what values are being set. For instance. You can put a check in your set so that the age is never less than 4

```
public void setAge(int age) throws Exception {
  if (age <= 3) {
    throw new Exception("Age must be more than 3");
  }
  this.age = age;
}
```

Setting this with properties is left to the programmer, who may miss the check somewhere in the code. Debugging that later is very tricky.

Setters and getters also help to add logs / breakpoints to check the behavior of the program.

And most decent IDEs allow you to automatically code setters and getters just from the properties, so it is not a big deal.

As a side note, I would usually recommend storing birth dates and calculating age when needed, since age is a value that changes while birth date not, and you can always calculate ages from birth dates but not the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quick. I will change from age to birth. That was a slip up on my part. It makes total sense to use birth date instead!

Comment: I yhink you missed the point of that question, assuming that no getters and setters is equal to having public (anyway not private) fileds. I think the real question is - do you really need setters and getters to make class having private fields to be perfectly valid?

Comment: Sorry for commenting twice in reply. I cant figure out how to edit my first reply. My original question though is, as the code stands, if I was to delete the getters and setters from the Name, Address and Student classes would the code work? I understand their value and why they should be used, but as far as I can tell they're not being used in the current code, they're just there and could be removed. Is this an accurate assumption?

Comment: No. `private` means that the attributes can only be accesed by methods of the class. It is not relevant if there are setters or getters or any other methods that use it. To acess the attributes from other classes, you need just to change the scope to `public`, `protected` or default scope. The presence/absence of getters/setters or other methods is not relevant. Of course, if you use getters/setters it is better to make the attributes `private` so you can ensure that no all access to them is through the appropiate methods.

Comment: I commented out the getters and setter in the Name class and the code compilled with no errors so they are redundant at the moment. I think the best approach to take is to edit the code so that they no longer are redundant, but I'm a little bit lost as to the best approach to do this if I'm honest. If I took **age** as an example because you have done the same above. How would I go about making changes so that it could only be accessed through the getters and setters? I know I'd have to make Student() private in the student class for a start.

Comment: `age` is already ok at your code (private attribute, can only be accessed through methods). You do not have to make the constructor private

Comment: I know it's okay at the moment. What I'm wondering is how I would go about altering my code so that it would be necessary to use getters and setters to alter or access it. I'm not sure where to start once I have made the student object private.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies btw SJuan76. They are very helpful

Comment: I've read over your comments again and realised it's the private atributes that need getters and setters. What I'm wondering how to do is to alter the code to make this happen. I see why I don't need to make the constructor private now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why they would be necessary at this time, though that is easy enough to verify by removing them. As Java is a compiled language you would generally get an error already at compile-time if other parts of the code were using those methods (unless parts of your code or a framework you use is using reflection).

Maybe the person you are coding with is planning to add some sort of Object-Relational-Mapping framework that would require those methods?

Personally I would say that you should never add code that isn't used. The main contributer to complexity of a codebase is the number of lines of code it has so there really is no reason to have anything in there that isn't in use.

Comment: I commented out all the getter and setters in the Name class and the program complies with no errors so that solves that issue for me. I think the way to proceed now is to edit the code so that the getters and setters are actually used.

Comment: Yeah, a comment about why it is downvoted would be nice as I am not sure which part people are disagreeing with.

Answer (score 0):

In support of SJuan76's write-up, and counter to another write-up - this needs to be said:

By establishing and using getter/setters from the very beginning you've enabled your code to have all the bounds-checking, logging, etc. in the future (if you don't do them now) WITHOUT requiring client-code to adapt to a conversion TO getter/setters.

It's a best-practice that will save you much more time later.

You should always consider that the code you write today WILL establish the interface for that code tomorrow.  Get it right/flexible/maintainable the first time.

Comment: If you're saying to use getters/setters over public/protected properties then I would agree. If you're saying to blindly add getters (and especially setters) to every private field I would strongly disagree. Some properties are probably not meant to be changed (date of birth is a good example and database ids are an even better one) and especially because the code you write today MIGHT establish an interface tomorrow at least some thought should go into it.

Comment: @ivarni I agree.  The point is to define the **right** interface now in the most **useful/flexible** way.  Adding elements later is a minimally-disruptive change.  Adding a getter/setter to a (currently) private element is therefore less disruptive.  Changing access from a field to a getter/setter is disruptive. [all changes are disruptive to serialization]